# t sql derive column based on date of row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I apologise for asking a question I'm sure is answered many times over but I can't quite word it to search for it. Even a link to a similar problem would be much appreciated.

If I have a table like so:

```
+----+----------+-----+
|Name|Date      |Score|
+----+----------+-----+
| Tom|2018-20-11|  100|
| Tom|2018-13-11|   95|
+----+----------+-----+
```

how would I query this so that each row would show a column for score today, score one week ago etc.? In this example with sample data it would be one row e.g.

```
+----+----------+-----------+
|Name|ScoreToday|Score-7Days|
+----+----------+-----------+
| Tom|       100|         95|
+----+----------+-----------+
```

I've seen similar problems solved via cross apply buy I can't work it out. Thanks for your help :)

Some sample code:

```
if exists (select * from sys.tables where name = 'test') drop table test
go
create table test (
    Name varchar(128)
    , AsAt datetime
    , Score int
)

insert test values ('Tom', getdate(), 87)
    , ('Tom', getdate() - 2, 100)
    , ('Tom', getdate() - 7, 95)
    , ('Tom', getdate() - 1, 81)
    , ('Tom', getdate() - 30, 95)
```

Comment: How many dates can be there per Name in the input table?

Comment: Are you wanting to combine and aggregate? Or do you just want to pivot rows into columns?

Comment: Would it always be 7 days back from today?   Or todays score and the score within the last 7 days or that?

Comment: This is called Pivot. Plenty of examples on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, there will be many dates, I want a few samples, I don't think I want to aggregate, just want a row taking certain dates as columns e.g. one week ago, one month ago, 3 months ago

If it can be done in either pivot/unpivot/cross apply I'd like to see it in this example I would appreciate that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([Name] varchar(4), [Date] datetime, [Score] int);

INSERT INTO T
    ([Name], [Date], [Score])
VALUES
    ('Tom', '2018-11-20 00:00:00', 100),
    ('Tom', '2018-11-13 00:00:00', 95),
    ('Sami', '2018-11-13 00:00:00', 55),
    ('Sami', '2018-11-15 00:00:00', 44);

DECLARE @Dates NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @Dates = @Dates + ',' + QUOTENAME([Date])
FROM T
GROUP BY [Date];

SET @Dates = STUFF(@Dates, 1, 1, '');

SET @SQL = N' SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM T) TT PIVOT( MAX(Score) FOR [Date] IN ('+ @Dates +')) PVT;';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Name | Nov 13 2018 12:00AM | Nov 15 2018 12:00AM | Nov 20 2018 12:00AM |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Sami |                  55 |                  44 |                     |
| Tom  |                  95 |                     |                 100 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf5c302d033b122a8f2b8f513479d6ac)**

Comment: This is almost it, is the dynamic sql for picking up the dates? Because if it can be done without dynamic sql, I will always be picking a certain number of days previous to today. Thanks for your help